# Tabla bidimesional

Tags: javascript

Edito pregunta.

Tengo una primera tabla con los siguientes datos:

```
var taula1 = [8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1,4.6,7.5,9.9,8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1,4.6,7.5,9.9,8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1];
```

El tema es que tengo que crear una tabla bidimensional para que cada 7 notas haga un salto, ya que cada 7 notas sera un alumno.

```
var taula1 = [8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1,4.6,7.5,9.9,8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1,4.6,7.5,9.9,8.6,7.5,6.9,9.2,5.1];

for (var i = 0; i < taula1.length; i++) {
  taula1[i] = Array(7);
}


console.log(taula1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la manera más sencilla sería utilizar [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para ir quitando trozos del array original e irlos guardando en el array de salida.

```js
var taula1 = Array.from(Array(140).keys())

function arrayAMatriz(miArray, columnas) {
  let matrizSalida = [];
  while (miArray.length > 0) {
    matrizSalida.push(miArray.splice(0, columnas))
  }
  return matrizSalida;
}

console.log(arrayAMatriz(taula1,7))
```

Versión "más sencilla" (o mejor dicho más didáctica):

```js
var taula1 = Array.from(Array(140).keys())

let arrayFinal = [];
let arrayTemporal = [];

for (i = 0; i < taula1.length; i++) { //Recorremos el array
  arrayTemporal.push(taula1[i]); //Guardamos cada elemento que recorremos en un array temporal
  if (i !== 0 && (i + 1) % 7 === 0) { //Si la cuenta es un multiplo de 7
    arrayFinal.push(arrayTemporal); //Guardamos el array con los siete números en el array final
    arrayTemporal = []; //Reiniciamos el array
  }
}

console.log(arrayFinal)
```

Sería más sencillo utilizar un `for.. of` si vas a recorrer un array en vez de utilizar un `for` con un contador. Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda para entender, te comenté todo para que lo puedas entender mejor.

Update2: Si quieres crear arrays vacíos:

```js
var taula1 = Array(140);
let taula2 = [];
let tamano = 7;

for (let i = 0; i < (taula1.length / tamano); i++) {
  taula2[i] = Array(tamano);
}

console.log(taula2)
```

Otra manera:

```js
let taula1 = Array(140);
let tamano = 7;

let taula2 = Array(taula1.length / tamano, ).fill(0).map(
  () => (Array(tamano))
);

console.log(taula2)
```

Comment: El tema es que necessito que sea mucho mas sencillo ya que todavia no hemos dado todo lo que me cuentas.

Comment: @Joan Te actualicé la respuesta utilizando métodos más básicos.

Comment: el console.log solo me saca 19 tablas cuando tiene que ser 20. Porque es eso?

Comment: Yo tengo esto pero por pantalla se me muestran los 140 elementos:
var taula1 = Array(140);
var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  taula1[i] = Array(7);
}

console.log(taula1)

Comment: @Joan whoops, disculpa tienes razón, eso es porque la indexación de los `array` que comienzan en cero, entonces en ese código que te puse nunca se hace el último pedazo... Ya lo corrijo

Comment: @Joan Listo! Ahora sí funciona correctamente

Comment: @Joan whoops acabo de actualizar con lo que tengo hecho,a ver si lo ves bien

Comment: @Joan Mi código esta basado en que necesitas partir de una array que ya contiene elementos... Si lo que quieres es que estén vacios como tu ejemplo todo es mucho más sencillo, ni si quiera ocuparías iterar sobre el array. Solo necesitarías saber su tamaño de antemano, actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: acabo de modificar mi pregunta ya que no la habia formulado bien

Comment: @Joan Los primeros dos ejemplos son solución a lo que describes.